# Get the longest path in a graph with OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'm a newbie with OrientDB and Graph (database and concept). I want to understand how to find the longest path in graph.

This is my graph:
[image]

The **shortest** path is: 13:0 -> 13:1 -> 13:2 (with sst() or dijkstra())

But I want to get the **longest**: 13:0 -> 13:3 -> 13:1 -> 13:2

How can I do? I must create from scratch a new function?

Thanks in advance

Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking a solution to a NP-hard problem :)
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).